# Include a external PHP file into a Wordpress Custom Template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, include-path

Is this even possible? I mean, im trying to add a blog into my site.. I already have the header,footer and sidebar layout in my site. can i use those in my custom wordpress template?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>
<?php include( PATH . 'http://www.mysite.com/includes/header.php' );  ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a></h2>
  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
  <div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="postmetadata">
    <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
    Posted in
    <?php the_category(', ') ?>
    |
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="mypagination">
  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>Not Found</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php include( PATH . 'http://www.mysite.com/includes/sidebar.php' );  ?>
<?php include( PATH . 'http://www.mysite.com/includes/footer.php' );  ?>
```

I also tried..

`<?php include('http://mywebsite.com/includes/header.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the php files you want to include are on the same server as the page you are creating, try including the .php files by their system path, which will probably be something like `/var/www/path/to/header.php`, at least for most unix-based servers.

Comment: you mean like this? <?php include( '/httpdocs/includes/header.php' );  ?>

Comment: yea, that's the way to do it.

Comment: Is there an error message? I would use a few `ls -l` commands to check the permissions, and make sure that the user/group running the main php file has read access to the included files.